# Objective-C 2.0: class_copyPropertyList(), how to list properties from categories

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I tried to list all properties of an Objective-C class like described in the [Objective-C 2.0 Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html):

```
id LenderClass = objc_getClass("UIView");
unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(LenderClass, &outCount);
for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", property_getName(property), property_getAttributes(property));
}
```

But this lists only three properties:

```
userInteractionEnabled Tc,GisUserInteractionEnabled
layer T@"CALayer",R,&,V_layer
tag Ti,V_tag
```

Looking at the header file for UIView.h those are the three properties directly declared in the class. The other UIView properties are added through categories.

How do I get all properties of a class, including those coming from categories?

I tried this with the iPhone simulator (iPhone SDK 2.2.1), btw. (in case this is important).

Comment: Maybe they are declared as dynamic and not synthesized due to CALayer? And therefore not visible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on my tests here, properties from categories will show up when using `class_copyPropertyList`. It looks as though the properties you're seeing on UIView are only *described* as properties in the public headers, not actually declared as such when building the UIKit itself. Probably they adopted the property syntax to make the creation of the public headers a little quicker.

For reference, here's my test project:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject
{
    NSString * str1;
    NSString * str2;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * str1;
@end

@interface TestClass (TestCategory)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * str2;
@end

@implementation TestClass
@synthesize str1;
@end

@implementation TestClass (TestCategory)

// have to actually *implement* these functions, can't use @synthesize for category-based properties
- (NSString *) str2
{
    return ( str2 );
}

- (void) setStr2: (NSString *) newStr
{
    [str2 release];
    str2 = [newStr copy];
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([TestClass class], &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", property_getName(property), property_getAttributes(property));
    }

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
str2 T@"NSString",C
str1 T@"NSString",C,Vstr1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It really looks like something is special about the UIKit in this respect. But your example actually does not show this since it works as expected; i.e. it lists the str2 property (which is more than I get with UIView).

Comment: This is what I meant, above. The properties declared in the public headers for UIView aren't actually declared as properties in the source used to build the UIKit, so they're not actually stored as such in the ObjC runtime information in the binary. i.e. there are a bunch of getter/setter methods, and for the public headers they've just added property declarations instead of method declarations for brevity. If they really were properties, they would show up via class_copyPropertyList(), even if they were declared in categories.

Comment: You should call
  free(properties)
in the end (see documentation).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the class_copyPropertyList function does return properties defined in categories.

What's going on here, is that it only returns properties defined at the given class level - so you are only seeing the three properties defined in UIView, and none of the properties (normal or category) that are defined in the UIResponder and NSObject ancestors.

In order to achieve the full inherited listing; you must loop up through the ancestors via the Class.superclass reference and aggregate the results from class_copyPropertyList.  Then you will see, for example, the various properties defined in UIKits Accessibility category for NSObject.

I actually came here looking for a way to *exclude* the properties defined in categories from these results!

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to exclude properties from categories?

Comment: No - I don't think there is one.  The Objective-C runtime seems to be unaware of categories once they are loaded, which is probably a good thing on balance.  I ended up solving my problem another way.