# Get all UIView subviews with all property values, iOS

Tags: ios

I have a question about iOS programming.

I am trying to get all subviews from main UIView, and subview properties.
I am using delegate **"- (void)listSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view"**, but this method returns poorly described subview information.

For example:

```
 - "UIImageView: 0x1d557250; frame = (10 6.5; 32 32); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x1d557220",
 - "UILabel: 0x1d557190; frame = (50 0; 240 43); text = '11:00'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x1d557960",
```

- "UIView: 0x1d5568e0; frame = (110 10; 190 23); layer = CALayer: 0x1d5568b0",

But I want to get, for example, UILabel text color, font size and other information.
Is there some kind of method or objects which can help me get this information?

Comment: You could create a UIView category and override the `-(NSString *)description;` method. This is what is being displayed. Then you could write it so that it parses all properties.

Comment: possible answer http://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/objective-c-quickie-printing-all-declared-properties-of-an-object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (void)yourMethod{
    UIView *parnetView = ...;

    [parentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(printAllProperties)];
}

@interface UIView (printAllProperties)
- (void) printAllProperties;
@end

@implementation UIView (printAllProperties)

-(void)printAllProperties{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        unsigned int numberOfProperties = 0;
        objc_property_t *propertyArray = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &numberOfProperties);
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfProperties; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = propertyArray[i];
            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
            NSLog(@"Property %@ Value: %@", name, [self valueForKey:name]);
        }
        free(propertyArray);
    });    
}
@end
```

You need to add method **printAllProperties** as category to UIView

Comment: Thanks. With a little bit of editing ... and all worked out great. Got what I wanted.

But I have a question, can I get this working in GCD, or just on another thread?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there no method available in UIKit which will do that for you. You will have to query the runtime system to get this information. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774276/1407017) for more details (Upvote the answer in the link if you find it useful).

For understanding about ObjC runtime, read through [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001422-TPXREF101).

Hope that helps!