# Easy way to get array of properties of a custom NS object?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsobject

I have an NSObject with some properties as in:

```
public class Contact: NSObject {

var first: String = ""
var last: String = ""
var title: String = ""
//and so forth
}
```

Is there a simple way to get the values of the object properties for a single instance of the object, ie one Contact, into an array such as:

```
{"Bob","Smith","Vice President"}
```

I can't seem to find a straightforward way to do this.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844681/list-of-classs-properties-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caveman way:

```
public class Contact: NSObject {

  var first: String = ""
  var last: String = ""
  var title: String = ""

  var values: [String] {
    return [first, last, title]
  }
}
```

A more useful way, which allows you to serialize to NSKeyedArchiver, JSONEncoder, or whatever:

```
public class Contact: NSObject {

  var first: String = ""
  var last: String = ""
  var title: String = ""

  var values: NSDictionary {
    return [
      "first": first,
      "last": last,
      "title": title
    ]
  }
}
```

Either way, the simplest method is to manually scrape out the state properties you are interested in.

Comment: The class is in another file but I was able to use the manual method to create an array from the object.  Wish I could give extra +1 for caveman reference

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find the values of the Object's properties is to use the Mirror apis provided by apple. You can get properties values as

> Example Code

```
public class Contact: NSObject {
var first: String = ""
var last: String = ""
var title: String = ""
//and so forth

var values: [String] {
    return Mirror(reflecting: self).children.map {$0.value as? String ?? ""}
}
```