# Is reflection on Metatype?

Tags: swift, reflection

While it's possible to [get a list of properties from an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844681): it requires an instance which is troublesome if the Type isn't trivial and doesn't have a straightforward `.init()`.  Similarly, can't we test the existence of a nested type?

```swift
struct SomeStruct: Codable {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}
class CoolClass: Codable {
    var thing: SomeStruct
    var name: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "title", name = "stuff"
    }
}

func testA(_ type: Any.Type) {
    if type is Codable.Protocol {
        print("is Codable")
    } else {
        print("is NOT Codable")
    }
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: type)
    mirror.children  // << empty collection!!
}

func testB<T>(_ type: T.Type) where T: Codable {
    // test if `type` defines `CodingKeys` or if it is synthesized.
    
}

testA(SomeStruct.self)  // "is NOT Codable", can't get list of ["x", "y"]
                        // , nor can't get CodingKeys...
```

If there is no reflection for metatypes, my attempts at piggybacking off of `Codable`'s CodingKeys (explicit or synthesized) have all failed. Is this possible?

Comment: You might be facing an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284459). Let's start with what you are trying to accomplish to begin with, that led you to try to see if CodingKeys is synthesized or user-defined, whether you can reflect on a type, and so forth

Comment: @NewDev: **Requirement:** Obtain a list of a type's property names without requiring an instance of said type.

Comment: So, that's an attempted *solution* to some original problem, which now faces its own problem. What is that original problem? It might be that the attempted solution is not needed at all

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve your main problem, but you are not checking correctly if `type` is codable. Since `type` is already a structure/class type (not an object), you should try to cast it from `Any.Type` to `Codable.Type`, which will only succeed if `type` implements `Codable`:

```
if type as? Codable.Type != nil {
    print("is Codable")
} else {
    print("is NOT Codable")
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you!   Not sure if this is worthy of its own question: But is the difference between both:  `Codable.Type` return a type whereas `Codable.Protocol` return a metatype?

Comment: @user1040049 they are both metatypes. The `type as Codable.Type` refers to "Codable nature" of the `type` you provided (i.e. all properties and functions of `type` that are related to implementation of `Codable`). While `Codable.Protocol` refers to protocol itself - same as `Codable.self`.