# objective c dynamically get a nsobjects properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsobject

I'm trying to dynamically get a class' properties. This is my method

```
+(NSArray *)getDictionaryKeysFromObjClass:(NSObject *)objClass{

    NSMutableArray *classProperties = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    const char* className = class_getName([objClass class]);
    id ObjectClass = objc_getClass(className);

    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(ObjectClass, &outCount);

    for(i=0; i<outCount; i++){
        objc_property_t *property = properties[i];
        //[classProperties addObject:property];
        NSLog(@"Property > %@", property);
    }

}
```

So I'm not sure if I was doing it correctly as whenver I call it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *testarr = [WCFServiceRequest getDictionaryKeysFromClass:[MyFirstClass class]];
```

It would throw an error:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[WCFServiceRequest
>   getDictionaryKeysFromClass:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!!

Comment: i insist you to [refer this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848636/objective-c-2-0-class-copypropertylist-how-to-list-properties-from-categorie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a typo

```
NSMutableArray *testarr = [WCFServiceRequest getDictionaryKeysFromClass:[MyFirstClass class]];
------------------------------------------------------------------^Obj is missing
```

It should be :

```
NSMutableArray *testarr = [WCFServiceRequest getDictionaryKeysFromObjClass:[MyFirstClass class]];
```

Since your method is :

```
+(NSArray *)getDictionaryKeysFromObjClass:(NSObject *)objClass;
```