# ios class_copyPropertyList return less count properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I call `class_copyPropertyList` in my function

```
+ (NSDictionary *)classPropsFor:(Class)klass{
    if (klass == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *results = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] ;

    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(klass, &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        const char *propName = property_getName(property);
        if(propName) {
            const char *propType = getPropertyType(property);
            NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName];
            NSString *propertyType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propType];
            if (propertyType != nil){
                [results setObject:propertyType forKey:propertyName];
            }
        }
    }
    free(properties);

    // returning a copy here to make sure the dictionary is immutable
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:results];
}
```

But for example class with 2 properties it's get different count of properties list: one time 0 count, else time 2, else time 1.

Why?

This is happening on iOS 7

Comment: Probably the reason is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/850034/1228534

Comment: Problem is runtime return NSNumber<#\xa5\x02\x8c\a and it's can be converted to type.